# kubernetes is exposing not declared port

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, port, gunicorn

I didn't expose any port in kubernetes/docker but i'm still able to connect to python app from another pod.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8
.
.
.
.

RUN chmod u+x /app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /app/entrypoint.sh $WORKERS $FLASK_APP
```

This is the entrypoint

```
flask db upgrade -d abc/migration
gunicorn -w $1 -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:7103 $2
```

This is deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 labels:
   app: nw-microservice  
 name: nw-microservice  
 namespace: nw-microservice-stg 
spec:
 replicas: 1
 strategy:
   rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 20%
     maxUnavailable: 0
   type: RollingUpdate
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: nw-microservice  
   spec:
     containers:
       - env:
           - name: "PYTHONPATH"
             value: "/app"
         image: imageurl
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         name: nw-microservice-api  
         terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
         terminationMessagePolicy: File
     dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
     imagePullSecrets:
       - name: shared-account-ecr
     restartPolicy: Always
```

This is the service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: service  
 namespace: namespace  
spec:
 ports:
   - name: http
     port: 7103  
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 7103
 selector:
   app: nw-microservice  
 type: ClusterIP
```

So i can connect the pod through http://service.namespace:7103 but i don't understand why.

Comment: (a) you did not post the descriptor for the `Service` (b) kubernetes does not default to restricting in-cluster traffic. If that is a concern of yours, you will want to use [network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to lock down traffic accordingly. If they defaulted to denying traffic, SO would be **filled** with questions that are the opposite of yours

Comment: (a) I already updated the post fir the service.

Comment: (a) I already updated the post fir the service.
(b) I understand kubernetes doesn't restrict in-traffic traffic but i don't understand the way the traffic reach the cointainer (i never write EXPOSE 7103 inside Dockerfile) nor write the port in the deployment manifest
          `ports:
            - containerPort: 7103
              name: http
              protocol: TCP`

Answer (score 2):

The ports defined in a container are purely informational:

> Exposing a port here gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily **informational**. **Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed**. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network.

You can have a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workloads-resources/container/#ports)